# How do I make an element slide in after 3 seconds of page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make an element on my webpage slide in after 3 seconds, and once user get it active (select what they want), it slides out automatically.

I want the element to be hidden upon load, untill 3 seconds before it slides in. And once user selects what they want, it slides out.

I've made my research but all I can see is with a button attached. How do I make this happen without that. Automatically.

- JavaScript might be involved but I don't know how to go about that.

Please I really would appreciate any suggestion

```
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

#mmj {
    position: relative !important;
  /* This section calls the slideInFromRight animation we defined above */
  animation: 2s ease-out 3s 1 slideInFromRight !important;
}
```

```
<div id="mmj">
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<div class="vl"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: learn what you can then try then post the code you tried here in an executable snippet. then we can help. don't ask like this or your question will get disliked and maybe closed. good luck.

Comment: @Mad7Dragon I just did that brother. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- the code you provided doesn't reproduce any issue.

2- according to your words

> I want the element to be hidden upon load, until 3 seconds before it slides in. And once user selects what they want, it slides out.

I simply used `margin` to achieve that. here is the code.

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container");
let btns = container.children;

setTimeout(() => {
    container.style.marginRight = "0px";
}, 3000); // to slide it in after 3 seconds

for (const btn of btns) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", clicked =>{
        container.style.marginRight = "-350px";
        // to slide it out after clicking one of the cards.
    })
};
```

```css
body {
    background: lightgrey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
}

#container {
   background: lightcoral;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: -350px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.btn {
    width: 33%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container" id="container">
    <button class="btn">click me</button>
    <button class="btn">click me</button>
    <button class="btn">click me</button>
    <button class="btn">click me</button>
    <button class="btn">click me</button>
    <button class="btn">click me</button>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I needed the element to slide in from the right. Also it is the Google Translate Element (already has selectable choices of language) just as seen in the snippet ```id="google-translate-element"```, so I don't need a btn in the element I guess

Comment: your element is just a div, my element is just a div. you can just change the margin to right. the buttons are just examples of the function, you can replace them with whatever you want.

Comment: I changed the slide from right @JohnnybleeRowland